# Please help with resistor color code?

Tags: resistors

I have trouble with finding out resistance of a resistor. It has 5 bands but somehow I cant get the code right.

[image]

Comment: Funny that it appears to cross what seems to be the isolation barrier.

Comment: it actually does cross isolation barrier, would that affect type of resistor?

Comment: Good question. I wouldn't think _any_ resistor could cross an isolation barrier worth its salt - no matter its value. Maybe that information helps to identify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my best attempt: -

[image]

- 1st band is grey because the 2nd band can't be gold (see above) = 8
- 2nd band is red hence = 2
- 3rd band is green = 5

This makes the value 8.2 Mohm

The gold band makes it a 5% resistor and the final white band is the tricky one but I suspect it should be regarded as a "null" (or nil) band and meaningless as implied in this picture: -

[image]

The final white band *could* imply a 20% tolerance.

Comment: Hi Andy, that's what I thought as well, it's that white band which makes it a bit confusing. Do you think it might be temperature related or reliability?

Comment: @Dean80 I had considered that but I can find no evidence that that is the case.

Comment: white band might be just for reading indication, it seams to be slightly wider as well